# Appcelerator Titnaium - enable-launch-screen-storyboard takes wrong file

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've set up all my icons, splash screen & itunes artwork graphics on a new project, and in `tiapp.xml` I've set the 'enable-launch-screen-storyboard' to true - what it shows instead of the splash screen is the icon of the app, and that doesn't even take the entire screen - just a square in the middle with white background surrounding it.

If I set `enable-launch-screen-storyboard` to false - I see the splash screen I expect.

What splash screen file, and in what size, should I set to use `enable-launch-screen-storyboard` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new feature in the - yet unreleased - Titanium 5.2.0 SDK. It uses an image set called LaunchLogo from the asset catalog. By default, it will generate LaunchLogos based on the `LaunchLogo.png`. If `LaunchLogo.png` doesn't exists, it will fall back to either `DefaultIcon-ios.png` or `DefaultIcon.png` (which is what you saw). You can manually create them in the `Resources/iphone` (`app/assets/iphone` for Alloy) directory if you like.

Comment: Thanks. I'm testing out future version as well :) since app I'm writing not going to production any time soon...